# R + xyplot + key with multiple references

Tags: r, key, lattice

I have a plot that is similar to this:

```
w=rnorm(9)
z=rnorm(9)
A=as.factor(c(rep(c("A1","A2","A3"),3)))
B=as.factor(c(rep("B1",3),rep("B2",3),rep("B3",3)))
C=as.factor(c("C1","C1","C2","C2","C3","C3","C1","C2","C3"))

xyplot(w~z,type="p",cex=1.4,
       panel=function(x, y, ...) {
         panel.xyplot(x=z[1], y=w[1],pch=15,col="red",...);
         panel.xyplot(x=z[2], y=w[2],pch=15,col="green",...);
         panel.xyplot(x=z[3], y=w[3],pch=15,col="blue",...);
         panel.xyplot(x=z[4], y=w[4],pch=16,col="red",...);
         panel.xyplot(x=z[5], y=w[5],pch=16,col="green",...);
         panel.xyplot(x=z[6], y=w[6],pch=16,col="blue",...);
         panel.xyplot(x=z[7], y=w[7],pch=17,col="red",...);
         panel.xyplot(x=z[8], y=w[8],pch=17,col="green",...);
         panel.xyplot(x=z[9], y=w[9],pch=17,col="blue",...);
         ltext(x=x, y=y+0.1, labels=C)
})
```

And now I have been trying a lot without success to get a key like this:

[image]

I tried with key function, with legend function, trying to create more than one key in the same graph… I’m lost!!

Answer (score 0):

I know you are doing this in `lattice`, but `ggplot` makes this kind of thing pretty easy.

```
my.data<-data.frame(w,z,A,B,C)
ggplot(my.data,aes(x=w,y=z,colour=A,shape=B,label=C)) + 
  geom_point(size=3) + 
  geom_text(hjust=-0.2,vjust=-0.2)
```

[image]

I had a hard time figuring out how to get a guide for the labels. But then I realized that if you have the labels, why do you need a guide?